# How do I open the Bluetooth Settings Activity programmatically?

Tags: android, android-intent, settings

I want to open bluetooth settings on button click 
like this see image[image: bluetooth image]

**HomeActivity.java**

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                final ComponentName cn = new ComponentName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.bluetoothSettings");
                intent.setComponent(cn);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity( intent);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Checkout this answer on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4227354/1297609

Answer (score 18, accepted):

use

```
ComponentName cn = new ComponentName("com.android.settings", 
                   "com.android.settings.bluetooth.BluetoothSettings");
```

instead of

```
final ComponentName cn = new ComponentName("com.android.settings", 
                              "com.android.settings.bluetoothSettings");
```

to launch BluetoothSettings settings

Comment: but is also display the other settings i want show only bluetooth settings all other must be hide

Comment: and i am use the android 4.0.3 tablet

Comment: @AndroidNewc: this code for launching  BluetoothSettings settings  Activity and it's not possible i think to remove all other Options  from Setting activity

Comment: IMHO this can crash with any new android version

Comment: Works on API 26 (Android 8). "setAction" solution doesn't work on API 26.

Comment: startActivity(Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS))

Answer (score 68):

Maybe I missed something but isn't this simpler future proof solution?

```
Intent intentOpenBluetoothSettings = new Intent();
intentOpenBluetoothSettings.setAction(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS); 
startActivity(intentOpenBluetoothSettings);
```

It is definitely not possible to "remove" the other settings. On phones just one category of settings is shown. On tablets, because of some extra space, settings are shown in master-detail layout so there is no empty space on more the half of the tablet screen. This is how Android is designed and just by writing one app that can not be changed.

As suggested by @zelanix the `BLUETOOTH_ADMIN` permission in manifest is required.

Comment: This seems to be the better solution to me. Just a comment (this applies to both solutions) that this requires the `BLUETOOTH_ADMIN` permission.

Comment: Is there any way to get this settings window to open 'non-modally' from your app? The only way to get back to the app was via the 'back' button next to the home button, rather than the two windows appearing separately in the 'task list' view of apps as I would have expected. 
(Perhaps this 'modal' method is the preferred, standard, technique though? Apologies, I'm a v new newb when it comes to Android as a user & developer)

Comment: Ted, did you ever figure out a better way?

Comment: This should not require BLUETOOTH_ADMIN and doesn't on stock Android -- may be a manufacturer bug. I reported this one to Samsung.

Comment: I think starting with sdk v23 / Android 6 you need at least  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" /> and perhaps the _ADMIN one as well

Comment: Does't work on API 26 (android 8). No activity found to handle the intent ACTION_BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS. Accepted answer works on API 26.

Comment: android.settings.BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS works for me on Android 8.0.

Comment: In Android "Q" we get Settings.Panel .
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Panel.html#ACTION_NFC
It does not support bluetooth yet (just NFC) but this is something to look out for to "remove the other settings" and get just a Bluetooth ON/OFF -switch.

Answer (score 34):

I think you should try this easier one :

```
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS));
```

Comment: This is indeed correct answer. Tested on Android 5.0.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to open up the scan dialog (without leaving your app).

```
    Intent bluetoothPicker = new Intent("android.bluetooth.devicepicker.action.LAUNCH");
    startActivity(bluetoothPicker);
```

[image: BluetoothScanDialog]

Answer (score 3):

Go to Bluetooth Setting:

Java:

```
startActivity(new Intent().setAction(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS));
```

As Below->

```
BtnOpenSetting.setOnClickListener (v->{
startActivity(new Intent().setAction(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS));
});
```

Kotlin:

```
startActivity(Intent().setAction(Settings.ACTION_BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS))
```

As Below->

```
BtnOpenSetting.setOnClickListener {
startActivity(Intent().setAction(Settings.ACTION_BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS))
};
```

Answer (score 2):

adb shell am start -a android.settings.BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS

Comment: The question seems to be about doing it programmatically, not through command line.