# How can I open the settings page in the device using cordova

Tags: android, cordova, settings

I am building an application using apache cordova, and I already can check if the bluetooth is available using [the BluetoothSerial plugin](https://github.com/don/BluetoothSerial/).

If it is not then I redirect to a page where I have a button to call the device settings dialogue, but I cannot find any example of how to do this. Is it even possible?

I have found examples of getting the wifi / gps settings, but not the settings page itself.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you will need native code to call the bluetooth settings.

I'm assuming you know how to call java method from javascript. call this code

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
final ComponentName cn = new ComponentName("com.android.settings", 
              "com.android.settings.bluetoothSettings");
intent.setComponent(cn);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity( intent);
```

This should open the bluetooth settings. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13911468/how-to-open-bluetooth-settings-in-android) for more details.