# How to call the native window of Bluetooth settings on Android in Delphi?

Tags: android, delphi, bluetooth, settings

I've seen an app where its Bluetooth settings calls the native window of Android Bluetooth settings. When the user press Android Back button, it returns to the app. How does this call the native Bluetooth settings window in Delphi?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per: [How do I open the Bluetooth Settings Activity programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13911468/how-do-i-open-the-bluetooth-settings-activity-programmatically)

```
uses
  Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText, Androidapi.JNI.Provider, Androidapi.Helpers;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  LIntent: JIntent;
begin
  LIntent := TJIntent.Create;
  LIntent.setComponent(TJComponentName.JavaClass.init(StringToJString('com.android.settings'), StringToJString('com.android.settings.bluetooth.BluetoothSettings')));
  TAndroidHelper.Context.startActivity(LIntent);
end;
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me. Is there any user permissions that I need to set for this?

Comment: Works for me on my Nexus 5X running Android 8.1, starting from a blank project. What version of Android do you have, and are there any errors?