# How to open Android Settings App programmatically with Delphi?

Tags: android, android-settings, delphi

So I want to write a simple Delphi application with a button. When you click on this button then it should open the Settings App on Android. It should not open anything within the settings, but just the Settings app itself.

I want to do this programmatically. What's the code for this? How does one do this in Delphi?

Comment: Where is this a duplicate question? Please link me to that question.

Comment: The [linked duplication question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19517417/) explains how to launch the Settings app by starting an `Intent`. You can start an `Intent` in Delphi via `SharedActivity().startActivity()` or `TAndroidHelper.Activity.startActivity()`, depending on your version of Delphi.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't really help me much in Delphi as the code isn't exactly the same. It looks different in Delphi.

Comment: There are plenty of examples floating around of how to use Android Intents in Delphi, if you search around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
uses
  Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText, Androidapi.JNI.Provider, Androidapi.Helpers;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  LIntent: JIntent;
begin
  LIntent := TJIntent.JavaClass.init(TJSettings.JavaClass.ACTION_SETTINGS);
  LIntent.addFlags(TJIntent.JavaClass.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // <-- this might be optional
  TAndroidHelper.Context.startActivity(LIntent);
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

I asked something similar ... I did not test for your application, but I believe it works the same way:

[How to call the native window of Bluetooth settings on Android in Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49837861/how-to-call-the-native-window-of-bluetooth-settings-on-android-in-delphi)

Comment: How would the code look if you just want to open the Settings app and not something inside of the settings app? I tried removing the bluetooth part, I tried removing the entire StringToJString function for the bluetooth part and I tried adding a 0 instead of the StringToJString for bluetooth one.